# environment variable expansion in first line of shell script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, interpreter

My ruby shell scripts specify the ruby interpreter in the first line of the script as:

```
#!/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
```

The problem is that when I upgrade to a new ruby version, I have to edit all the script files to update the interpreter. There is an environment variable available, $MY_RUBY_HOME, that expands to the current path (minus the /bin/ruby part). However, all my attempts to use:

```
#!{$MY_RUBY_HOME}/bin/ruby
#!${MY_RUBY_HOME}/bin/ruby
etc
```

fail ("bad interpreter: No such file or directory"). I suspect environment expansion isn't done on the first line, so I may just be out of luck. I would be interested if anybody has been able to use environment variable expansion on the program definition line in a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `${MY_RUBY_HOME}/bin` in your `$PATH` and use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability).

Comment: Thanks!  Works like a charm!  And ruby was already in the path, so all I needed was the shebang line.